# List in Table fitting to text without space between words

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I already tried a lot but still cannot find a solution for my problem. I want a table similar to the one below. In the first column the sentences should be listed but without extra space between the top of the cell and the first item (what happens when I use itemize). The whole table should fit to the text of my paper and the cell width should fit to the content.
Can anybody help me?

[image: The table I want to have]

Edit: the **current code**, I am using (but without using the list function):

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|
   >{\setlength\hsize{1.4\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|
   >{\setlength\hsize{0.9\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|
   >{\setlength\hsize{0.7\hsize}\setlength\linewidth{\hsize}}X|}
\hline
1st Order Concepts & 2nd Order Themes & Aggregate Dimensions \\ 

\hline
- Umsatzsteigerung durch Sponsoring und Kooperation mit anderen Brauerei\newline
- Kleinbrauerei stösst an Produktionslimit, erhöht aber die Produktion nicht \newline
- Kleinbrauerei will organisch wachsen \newline
- Brauerei ruft Biertrinker auf, leere Flaschen zurückzubringen \newline 
- Kleinbrauereien sind agiler und können sich deshalb schneller anpassen \ 
&    
Nicht-Wachstumsstrategie, Nachhaltigkeit, Kooperation, Transparenz, Demokratie, familiärer Betrieb, Agilität &
Organisations-eigenschaft \\ 
\hline
- Frau in Führung von Brauerei \newline 
- Brauerin misst Erfolg daran, ob die Hefe aufgegangen ist\newline
- Kleinbrauerei setzt auf Lokalität \
&
Leidenschaft, gute Führung, Fürsorge, Selbstwirksamkeit, Diversität &
Mitarbeiter-eigenschaft \\ 
\hline
- Brauerei in Salzburg braut erstes biodynamisches Bier und braut abgestimmt auf Vollmond \ newline
- Kleinbrauerei ist erfolgreich wegen ihrer hohen Qualität \newline
- Kleinbrauerei hat Erfolg durch Spezialitätenbier und limitierte Produktion \ 
&
Regionalität, hohe Qualität, Vielfalt, limitierte Produktion, Spezialitäten & Produkt-eigenschaft \\ 
\hline
- Bier gehört zu vielen Anlässen dazu \newline
- Bei Tod von Brauerei-Gründer solidarisiert sich die ganze Stadt \newline
- Kleinbrauerei hat Erfolg mit Kombination aus Bier und Mate \newline 
- Kleinbrauerei ist erfolgreich mit Crowdfunding
&
Tradition, Heimat, Innovation, kleine Lieferanten, Beliebtheit, Innovation &
Branchen-eigenschaft \\ 
\hline
    
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could please post what you've tried (even if unsuccessful) so we don't have to retype everything?

Comment: As starting point can serve https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549732/adjusting-one-column-width-while-others-remain-same-in-tabular-environment/549744#549744. For adoption it to your table you need to provide MWE (Minimal Working Excmple), a small complete document with your table (that we not need to retype your table).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers!! I edited my post with the code I am currently using

Comment: The hard-coded hyphen in the "...-eigenschaft" in the last column is not the best idea. If you want to allow hyphenation in the first word in a table cell, you can use `>{\hspace{0pt}...`. In combination with Zarko's solution, the code could look like the following : `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}L|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize\hspace{0pt}}L|}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the use of the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % optional
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e,makecell,tabularx,caption}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{% % variable-width X-type columns
    >{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}%
      \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}   % <-\item   defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{label =-, nosep, left=0pt,
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize},
                  after =\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{My table}
\label{tab:features}
    \setcellgapes[t]{2pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|L{1.5}|L{0.9}|L{0.6}|} 
    \hline
    1st Order Concepts & 2nd Order Themes & Aggregate Dimensions    \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Umsatzsteigerung durch Sponsoring und Kooperation mit anderen Brauerei
    \item   Kleinbrauerei stösst an Produktionslimit, erhöht aber die Produktion nicht
    \item   Kleinbrauerei will organisch wachsen
    \item   Brauerei ruft Biertrinker auf, leere Flaschen zurückzubringen
    \item   Kleinbrauereien sind agiler und können sich deshalb schneller anpassen 
    \end{tabitem}
    & Nicht-Wachstumsstrategie, Nachhaltigkeit, Kooperation, Transparenz, Demokratie, familiärer Betrieb, Agilität 
    & Organisations\-eigenschaft \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Frau in Führung von Brauerei
    \item   Brauerin misst Erfolg daran, ob die Hefe aufgegangen ist
    \item   Kleinbrauerei setzt auf Lokalität 
    \end{tabitem}
    & Leidenschaft, gute Führung, Fürsorge, Selbstwirksamkeit, Diversität 
    & Mitarbeitereigenschaft     \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Brauerei in Salzburg braut erstes biodynamisches Bier und braut abgestimmt auf Vollmond 
    \item   Kleinbrauerei ist erfolgreich wegen ihrer hohen Qualität
    \item   Kleinbrauerei hat Erfolg durch Spezialitätenbier und limitierte Produktion 
    \end{tabitem}
    & Regionalität, hohe Qualität, Vielfalt, limitierte Produktion, Spezialitäten 
    & Produkteigenschaft       \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabitem}
    \item   Bier gehört zu vielen Anlässen dazu
    \item   Bei Tod von Brauerei-Gründer solidarisiert sich die ganze Stadt
    \item   Kleinbrauerei hat Erfolg mit Kombination aus Bier und Mate
    \item   Kleinbrauerei ist erfolgreich mit Crowdfunding
    \end{tabitem}
    & Tradition, Heimat, Innovation, kleine Lieferanten, Beliebtheit, Innovation 
    & Brancheneigenschaft    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code a bit, mainly to make the handling of variable-width X-type columns more robust. (In your code, the relative column widths added up to 2, not 3, but somehow the table came out alright anyway. But I suspect that was more a fluke.)

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much! Now specification of columns is more correct. I didn't pay enough attention to sum of columns width (only consider that should be integer :-( ).

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was exactly the problem, the width of my columns changed randomly.